# jQuery alert with an array of id

Tags: jquery

I've this code example, to define my problem : jsfiddle.net/Architecte/KSDCM/

Can you help me to call the select in question?

Do you know why I can not call an id that contains hooks?
Do I need to perform a specific action to do this?

In fact if I renommme selct my id in a "normal", everything works perfectly.

But for me to validate my post later in this call, I have to keep these tables up.

Comment: For your `name` attribute, you can use `[]` perfectly. They are not really allowed for `id` attributes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the special characters with `\\`:

```
$('#f1\\[sector\\]')
```

See http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you [ and ] in your elements id

Comment: Yes I know this, but this is how can I ignore or consider?

Answer (score 0):

Like Tetaxas said, you can either escape special characters in the id, or use this selector instead

```
$('select[id="f1[sector]"]').html();
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/KSDCM/2/).

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('#newtechnicalsheet').click(function() {
    alert($('select[id="f1[sector]"]').html());
});
```

or

```
$('#newtechnicalsheet').click(function() {
    alert($('select[name="f1[sector]"]').html());
});
```